# Can clang-format be configured for different column limits for block comments and code?

Tags: c++, clang-format

An 80 character limit is an unreasonable relic for code itself, but it is quite nice for block comments, which are usually written as paragraphs. I can't figure out how to configure clang-format with a column limit for only block comments though. It looks like there is a single ColumnLimit option that applies to everything. Is it possible to have different limits?

Comment: "An 80 character limit is an unreasonable relic for code itself" [citation needed]

Comment: I'm curious why one would want to have a different length limit for code vs documentation.  Personally I'd rather be consistent and use the same limit everywhere.

Comment: @Mat [As close to one as reasonable](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/5/29/1038).